# How to get one row from duplicated rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables SVC_ServiceTicket and SVC_CustomersVehicle

The table ServiceTicket has a column customerID which is a foreign key to CustomersVehicle.So in ServiceTicket  column customerID can have duplicate values.

When I do

```
select sst.ServiceTicketID,sst.CustomerID 
from ServiceTicket sst,CustomersVehicle scv 
where sst.CustomerID=scv.CV_ID
```

then it gives me duplicate customerID.So my requirement is if there are duplicate values of customerID then I want the latest customerID and as well serviceticket of that corresponding(latest customerID)

For example in the below screenshot there are customerID 13 is repeating so in this case I want latest customerID as well as serviceticket so the values I want is 8008 and 13

Please tell me how to do

[image]

Comment: You say `customerID ` but your query doesn't use it. Also, what means _latest_, according to what column(s)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry my bad,I did not want to show not necessary lines so while copying here missed the important part.Well when a new record is inserted it will be present at the last row,so I want the last row

Comment: A table has no implicit order. So there is no _first_ or _last_. You have to order a resultset to get an order. You could use your PK-column, but a datetime column would be better.

Comment: Tables are inherently unordered, you need something that provides an orderable value.  In this case, preferably a timestamp.  Autogen ids, despite appearing to be an increasing sequence, should not be relied upon for this type of use

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse ohh yes I have a column createdDate which is in float datatype.While inserting a record we are converting the date to float and storing it in float type

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes I have acolumn which is in float datetype,We are converting date to float type

Comment: ....whhhyyyyyy?   SQL Server has multiple native types for storing date-time values (which ones depends on version).....  Either way, this is really a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, which is usually solved via an OLAP windowing function, like `ROW_NUMBER()`, or `FIRST_VALUE()` (if a recent enough version).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse actually we have some problem while integrating with ms excel so decided not to use datetime datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregate function `MAX`. Also I would recommend to use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT MAX(sst.ServiceTicketID) AS ServiceTicketID,sst.CustomerID 
FROM ServiceTicket sst JOIN
     CustomersVehicle scv ON sst.CustomerVehicleID=scv.CV_ID
GROUP BY sst.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,why you said *Also I would recommend to use a JOIN.*

Comment: @javaprogrammer: Because, the best practice is to use `JOIN...ON...` syntax for joining two tables rather than mentioning the relation in where clause.